# Looking up a short name (non FQDN) from windows hosts file is slow

Tags: windows, dns, hosts, netbios, windows-networking

I am not sure what changed in my network setting in the office but recently when I look up an entry from my windows hosts file (using ping) it resolves the name with a 1-2 second pause ,but if I add the same name as an FQDN it is resolved very quickly. Any ideas ?

Test 1:
Add this to hosts file
192.168.100.100     server1

> ping server1
>   --> resolves the name after 2 seconds

Test 2:
Add this to hosts file
192.168.100.100     server1   server1.example.com

> ping server1.example.com
>   --> resolves the name quickly

Note : server1.example.com does not exist in any DNS. It is just an example. I use a different domain

Comment: How many DNS suffixes do your IP clients have (under TCP/IP advanced properties / DNS tab)?

Comment: There is no suffix defined there